# Computation of the complex roots of the Laplace transform of a function?

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, laplace-transform, spectral-theory

I have a function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}_+, \mathbb{R})$ with Laplace transform
$$ \forall \Re(z) \geq 0,~~ \hat{f}(z) := \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} { f(t) e^{-zt } dt}.$$

I know explicitly the expression of $f$.
I would like to compute **numerically** (an approximation of) the complex roots of $\hat{f}$, say the first 10 roots with the smallest real part. I want an effective algorithm (I do not require mathematical guarantees on the correctness of the roots!)

How should I do that?

---

The assumptions here are that $f$ is smooth, $f(t)$ (and its derivatives)  fast decay to zero as $t$ goes to infinity and I can compute numerically $f(t)$ for a fix $t$ quite fast.

What I tried is to first compute an approximation of $f$ is a weighted Laguerre polynomial basis - for which the Laplace transform is known explicitly - and then compute the roots using contour integrations on rectangles.
It works on toy examples but it is not very robust... So I would like to avoid to compute $\hat{f}$, if possible.

Comment: What is your function $f$. In general you can't prove easily that $F(z) \ne 0$ on a strip (try with $F(z-1/2)=\frac{1-1/z}{z^2}\zeta(z)$)

Comment: My function $f$ is smooth, $f(t)$ and its derivatives decay faster a $t \rightarrow \infty$ but its expression is messy ! I don't really hope any mathematical guarantees - what I want is an effective algorithm to compute approximation of those roots :)

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If you want an effective algorithm it means you have an effective function. To count the number of zeros in some rectangle we use the argument principle. In general that's the best we can do. Equivalently we plot $\Im (\log F(z))\bmod 2\pi$ and we detect the discontinuities (the points where all the [colors](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann) appear)

Comment: Yes, but the problem of such method is that I have to compute numerically the Laplace transform of $f$ before looking to its zeros. I tried that (by first computing an approximation of $f$ in the base of weighted Laguerre polynomials for which the Laplace transform is known explicitly) but it does not work very well in practice, because somehow my approximation of $\widehat{f}$ is not good enough. I was hoping to methods that does not require to compute "too much" the Laplace transform of my function - maybe spectral methods ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that there are "$10$ roots with the smallest real part".  That is, it is quite possible that there is an infinite sequence of roots with real parts positive but approaching $0$, and no roots with real part $0$.

Comment: You are right but I assume here that I have some garantees on the location of the roots. Anyway I don't require guarantees on the validity of the computed roots. I have added details to my question. Hope it is more precise now